# Query mongodb with php-mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building a simple messaging system, and i have a collection in mongodb with documents like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ad003f9811e5bc5c000000"), "between" : [ "user1,user2,user3" ] }
```

I want to perform this query:

```
db.conversations.find({'between': ["user1,user2,user3"]});
```

to get this exact document back. This query works in mongo shell.

in php-mongo, i tried this:

```
$collection->find(array("between"=>array("user1", "user2", "user3")));
```

but it does not work.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: no error, it only returns an empty result

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to do an In query here?

```
db.collection.find( { "between" : { $in : ["user1", "user2", "user3"] } } );
```

See In query here:
[Mongo Advanced $in query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in)

making your PHP query look like:

```
$collection->find(array("between"=>array("$in"=>array("user1", "user2", "user3"))));
//untested, should be something similar to this.
```

or if you're trying to find it exactly wouldn't you just be able to do:

```
$collection->find(array("between"=>array("user1,user2,user3")));
```

Comment: actually no, since the in operator matches a document that has any of the elements of the array. And i can't use the $all operator too, because i don't want to match a document that has all 3 users plus another one.

Comment: so you want to match only the documents that have exactly 1,2 and 3?

Comment: @QuArK: $collection->find(array("between"=>array("user1,user2,user3"))); doesn't work in your php? that would seem to simulate the exact query you have working in Mongo.. (notice the missing " separation between user's 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you are saving your data you have to use array not a string

```
{ "between" : [ "user1,user2,user3" ] }
```

this stores in "between" an array of one element `"user1,user2,user3"`

Basically when you do your query in shell everything is ok, because you are asking for a array with one element. But in php you are asking for an array of three elements.

So, when you save your data, most probably that is what you need :

```
{ "between" : [ "user1","user2","user3" ] }
```

and this will give you an array of three users.

Then read the documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries to and adjust your query depends on what you need: either the exact array or only some elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$collection->find(array("between"=>"user1,user2,user3"));
```

or

```
$collection->find(array( "$elemMatch" => array( "between"=>"user1,user2,user3" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$in` operator is analogous to the SQL `IN` modifier, allowing you to specify an array of possible matches.

Consider the following example which uses the `$or` operator.

```
$collection->find([
    'select' => ['$in' => ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']]
]);
```

[References](http://blog.uzaklab.com/post/37800389187/php-mongodb-advanced-queries)